# How to configure Windows Server as a Web Proxy?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows, transparent-proxy, web-proxy

I'd like to set up a transparent web proxy on my home network. I know you can do this with Squid on Linux. I was wondering if Windows Server includes a web proxy?

Comment: No, it doesn't have anything built it.  Even if you install Squid, it also doesn't have the required firewall features to act as a proxy  transparently.

Comment: So what are my options for a transparent web proxy? Only Squid on Linux?

Comment: Linux or BSDs.  Your other option is to give up on the transparent requirement.  Block output port 80/443 from everything but the squid host, and then require a proxy be configured on the clients.

Comment: There are some allegedly transparent proxy server apps for Windows, but having never tried them, I can't vouch that they'd actually work.  Hit up the Google for more info.

Comment: So if somebody would like to answer "No, use Linux. Here's how: [...]" , we can get an accepted answer.

Comment: @Zoredache : `Even if you install Squid, it also doesn't have the required firewall features to act as a proxy transparently` I am not sure to get what you mean here. Squid can act as a transparent Proxy even if it has not firewall features. I use Squid as a transparent Proxy in my corporation so i don't really understand...could you explain what you mean ? thanks in advance :)

Comment: @user2196728 I think Zoredache is referring to "Windows Server" when he says "it". As in 'Windows server won't let you configure the firewall appropriately to operate as a transparent web proxy,' even if you install squid on Windows.

Comment: Ha ok thanks, and sorry, i was thinking that `it` was a reference to Squid ;)

Comment: So this would be more relevant for SuperUser, then?

Comment: You can do this by installing squid in windows server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So if somebody would like to answer "No, use Linux. Here's how: [...]"
>   , we can get an accepted answer.

Ok so i would say : Microsoft has its own Firewall/Proxy product called Forefront TMG. So they won't kill themselves by providing such a role or feature on Windows 2008 Server.
However, it seems that they have announced the end of Forefront TMG (support still alive until april 2015 and april 2020 depending on contract subscribed). By now i don't know if it will be replaced by another product or added as a role/feature in future Windows OS version.

The fact is that the best and low-cost solution would be using Linux with the most popular proxy Squid.

Here is a link about how to configure it as a transparent Proxy :
http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy.html

Here an interesting resource also :
http://www.shorewall.net/Shorewall_Squid_Usage.html

Note that you will need to deal with `iptables` (most popular Linux firewall) to redirect traffic to the Proxy.

If you are not familiar with Linux i would suggest latest Ubuntu release (but not 13.10 because it has a limited time support). Ubuntu 12.04 LTS would be a much better choice (in my opinion). Debian 6/7 could be an alternative also.

ps : No, use Linux ! :)